# Rails 5 doesn't load js file in vendor/assets/javascripts directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I add some third-party JS libraries to the `vendor/assets/javascripts/tooltipster.js`. After that, I add in the `application.js`:

```
//= require tooltipster
```

, but I get this error:

`couldn't find file 'tooltipster' with type 'application/javascript'`

Checked in these paths:

```
  /home/masterbyter/Desktop/theaterway/app/assets/config
  /home/masterbyter/Desktop/theaterway/app/assets/images
  /home/masterbyter/Desktop/theaterway/app/assets/javascripts
  /home/masterbyter/Desktop/theaterway/app/assets/stylesheets
  /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/font-awesome-rails-4.7.0.2/app/assets/fonts
  /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/font-awesome-rails-4.7.0.2/app/assets/stylesheets
  /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/coffee-rails-4.2.2/lib/assets/javascripts
  /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/jquery-rails-4.3.1/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/actioncable-5.1.2/lib/assets/compiled
  /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionview-5.1.2/lib/assets/compiled
```

How to add third-party JS libraries in Rails 5 ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just include

```
//= require tooltipster.js
```

in `application.js` and you will need to restart your Rails server.

Comment: No need to restart the server on require any js in `application.js`

Comment: @puneet18 It *seems* that the asset paths array is populated once when the server starts. If any of the subfolders of `/vendor/assets/javascripts` did not exist then Rails will not be looking there.